BPE tokenizer add_tokens overlap with trained tokens
I am training a BPE from scratch. I want the vocabulary to include certain tokens that might or might not exist in the training dataset.
from datasets import load_dataset
from tokenizers import models, pre_tokenizers, trainers, Tokenizer, Regex

# Dataset
ds = load_dataset('HuggingFaceFW/fineweb', streaming = True)['train']
texts = [sample['text'] for sample in ds.take(10_000)]

# Init Tokenizer
tokenizer = Tokenizer(models.BPE(unk_token="<UNK>", byte_fallback = True))


# Special tokens
special_tokens = ["<UNK>", "<BOS>", "<EOS>"]
# Initial tokens
digits = [str(num) for num in range(10)]

tokenizer.add_special_tokens(special_tokens)
tokenizer.add_tokens(digits)

trainer = trainers.BpeTrainer(
    vocab_size=32_000,
    min_frequency=2,
    max_token_length = 32,
    show_progress = True
)
tokenizer.train_from_iterator(texts, trainer = trainer)

However, this results in overlap of token ids. It is observed as below:
vocab = {k: v for k, v in sorted(tokenizer.get_vocab().items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}
print(vocab)

{'\n': 0,
 '<UNK>': 0,
 '<BOS>': 1,
 ' ': 1,
 '<EOS>': 2,
 '!': 2,
 '0': 3,
 '"': 3,
 '#': 4,
 '1': 4,
 '$': 5,
 '2': 5,
 '%': 6,
 '3': 6,
 '4': 7,
 '&': 7,
 '5': 8,
 "'": 8,
 '6': 9,
 '(': 9,
 '7': 10,
 ')': 10,
 '8': 11,
 '*': 11,
 '+': 12,
 '9': 12

What is the proper way to add certain tokens (not special_tokens such as BOS EOS etc) when training a tokenizer via huggingface tokenizers framework?
